# Single .on click for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery...

```
$(".parentElem").on("click", "input[id*='myitem']", function() {
    myfunction();
});
```

and

```
$(".parentElem").on("click", "input[id*='myotheritem']", function() {
    myfunction();
});
```

These both work fine, but I don't want to have to list every clickable element separately... I'd much rather list them all at once - something like this...

```
$(".parentElem").on("click", "input[id*='myitem'], input[id*='myotheritem']", function() {
    myfunction();
});
```

Is this possible? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why not add a class and use that in your selection?

Comment: What are the actual elements you want to run `myfunction` on? Posting your HTML may help.

Comment: Why don't you use css selector :active???

Comment: Oops! Edited code... 2 and 3 were supposed to be different! Sorry!

Comment: It works just fine (nothing be should logged in the console for the 3rd input): http://jsfiddle.net/w536y/ . Are you sure you understand event delegation?

Comment: @Tom Check my answer, I don't understand why it's gotten a down vote. Seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: The 3rd is working, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument in the `.on()` method is a CSS selector. So you don't have to pass in each individual element with their ID. You could just use a generic class or selector like this:

```
$('.parentElem').on('click', 'input', function(event) {
    // Function body here
});
```

Comment: This would work, but there are other inputs on the page where I don't want to run this particular function...

Comment: Can you just use a class or a data- attribute to filter them?

Comment: So invent a new class (or, as suggested, add a data- attribute and use that in the selector) that is used on all the elements you want to have the same behavior. This is the solution, right here. +1 to the answer.

Comment: You can also use ":not" in your selector to filter out ones you don't want.

Comment: Example: 'input:not(.intro)'. Data- example: 'input[data-attribute=true]' where "attribute" is whatever the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use the delegation feature, instead do your own checking:

```
$(".parentElem").on("click", function() {
    // check if event.target matches an element that you want to trigger on
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
$(".parentElem").find("input[id*='myitem'], input[id*='myotheritem']").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        myfunction();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yA5gA/2/)

Comment: Where's the event delegation?

Comment: I don't see a need for delegation from my reading of the question.

Comment: All of the examples in the OP are with event delegation, meaning they want to use event delegation. You can't just blindly switch to direct event binding

Comment: If a user is hardcoding in ids then it's not likely there will be new DOM elements added after load, in which case, direct binding is a plausible solution. And since he was having problems with delegated versions, I believe a alternative solution is justifiable.

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to be hardcoding `id`s, and plenty of reasons why they would be dynamic. The selectors being used are the "attribute contains" selector, which means the `id`s have other content (maybe numbers), justifying why event delegation is (probably) necessary. So you can't just assume delegated events aren't applicable - we have no idea how this code is actually used. And if you want to assume something like that, you better explain it, otherwise your answer looks out of place and is downvoted

Comment: Agree to disagree, thanks for the dialog, better than a downvote with no discription.